# Is there a countdown timer application for elementary OS?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a simple application that provides a countdown timer and follows the [elementary OS HIGs](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need a [pomodoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) App

Well there are some that are specifically made for elementary.

### [Tomato](http://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Tomato/)

[image]

Tomato App is a time management application based on the Pomodoro technique, specially developed for the elementary OS 0.3 Freya and elementary OS 0.2 Luna systems.
You can use the stable PPA now:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tomato-team/tomato-stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tomato
```

[You can find others here.](http://www.junauza.com/2013/08/5-pomodoro-apps-for-linux-users.html)

Comment: That is beautiful.

Comment: OP requested a countdown timer. Pomodoro may not solve everyone's problem.

Answer (score 8):

## Go For it

Yep I did go fast and recommended a basic app (tomato) but I have dug one more out with more features, but it is doesn't look as good compared to tomato.

[image]

It does have a more configurable timer. It is a simple and stylish productivity app, featuring a to-do list, merged with a timer that keeps your focus on the current task.

To install it you can use this ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mank319/go-for-it && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install go-for-it
```

The github repo is at https://github.com/mank319/Go-For-It