# Install Gnome-Pomodoro

Tags: software-installation

Anyway to install [gnome-pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/) on ElementaryOS. I really like their feature. I found this: [Is there a countdown timer application for elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/384/is-there-a-countdown-timer-application-for-elementary-os/386#386) but this does not really have the feature I like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't work. The basic reason is that it's designed to work with the GNOME desktop environment and elementary OS uses Pantheon instead.

If you go to install it, it'll ask you to install a slew of GNOME-related dependencies. (It installs as `gnome-pomodoro` even though its install is `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-pomodoro`.) The settings will open, but I wasn't able to start the timer. This would be a nice app for someone to port to the elementary AppCenter. (Do note that [Tomato](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Tomato/) already exists as a elementary OS-specific app, though it's not in AppCenter yet.)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you download it for Ubuntu. elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 14.04 so most programs also work on elementary OS

Comment: Didn't work. Something wrong with gnome-shell

Comment: @mateeyow What is the error